# STL queue function: empty and size

Tags: stl, queue

Stl queue is used in our large program, with one line

```
if( q_block.empty() )
```

It returns true while it shouldn't.
And I change this code to

```
if( q_block.size() == 0 )
```

It returns false as it supposed to.
Reading the STL source code, I found that this two function quite the same. But I don't know why it behaves differently in this situation.

Can anyone give me some idea?

Comment: Which C++ compiler and standard library are you using? This makes a huge difference.

Comment: Next question. What type is backing your queue? The gcc stdlib's `std::queue::empty` and `std::queue::size` simply delegate to the equivalent functions in the underlying container.

Comment: Are you refering to the template type? It is a simple queue<int>. What confuse me is that, empty() and size() behave the same while I writing a simple test program on the same machine.

Comment: Okay, so the underlying type is `std::deque` then. You should check out how `std::deque::empty` is implemented in gcc's stdlib. It actually simply compares `begin()` to `end()`, and doesn't actually look at the size.

Comment: I add some codes to print the value of empty(). Some of them return strange values, such as 241975808. Did I overwrite the memory of queue?